# Angular + httpService: POST & DELETE results?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, typescript, angular-http

I've got an angular services which should do all the http stuff required to let my controllers talk with my API.

```
export interface IDummyEntityApiService {
    getAllDummies() : ng.IPromise<Array<Entities.IDummy>>;
}

class DummyEntityApiService implements IDummyEntityApiService {

    private http: ng.IHttpService;

    constructor($http : ng.IHttpService) {
        this.http = $http;
    }

    getAllDummies() {
        var url = "acme.com/api/dummies;
        return this.http.get(url).then(result => {
            return result.data;
        }, error => {
            // log error
        });
    }
}
```

Which I can then use like this:

```
dummyEntityApiService.getAllDummies.then(result => {
    // fill results into list
}, error => { 
    fancyToast.create("Ooops, something went wrong: " + error);
});
```

My question is now - how would this work with `POST` and `DELETE`? I know `$httpService` has methods like `.post(url, data)` and `.delete(url)`, and both of them return `IHttpPromise<{}>`, but casting them up to a `IPromise` doesn't really make sense since there is no data that needs to be resolved?

Comment: If id does not return anything, maybe try `IHttpPromise<void>`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use promise to execute something after HTTP request is finished. You can use `ng.IHttpPromise<any>`, for example.